# How to extract `hh:mm:ss` from `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss`

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following table
`timestamp(6) without timezone`

```
2000/01/01 0:00:00
2000/01/01 10:00:00
2000/01/01 04:00:00
```

I would like to get `hh:mm:ss`
My desired result is like follows

```
0:00:00
10:00:00
04:00:00
```

Are there any good ways of doing this?

Comment: [`to_char(col,'HH:MI:SS')`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE)

Comment: Not sure what happened here. This question clearly asks about dropping the date part and specifies output format. It's not a duplicate of the thread linked as duplicate, nor can we find an answer in that thread. Also, there was a good answer here that proposed `::time`, keeping a more flexible data type than `to_char()` - only short of rounding `::time(0)` to be perfect.

Comment: will `col - trunc(col)` work?

Comment: @tnavidi [`col - date_trunc('seconds',col)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) will return the truncated fractions of a second, not the time without them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [`to_char(col,'HH:MI:SS')`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) if you're only extracting to text. The function gives you a lot of formatting flexibility and truncates/discards everything after seconds, without rounding.
2. To trim leading zero like in presented desired results, you can add an [`FM` fill mode modifier prefix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE) to desired fields in `to_char()`.
3. [`col::time(0)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#:%7E:text=time%2C%20timestamp%2C%20and%20interval%20accept%20an%20optional%20precision%20value%20p%20which%20specifies%20the%20number%20of%20fractional%20digits%20retained%20in%20the%20seconds%20field.%20By%20default%2C%20there%20is%20no%20explicit%20bound%20on%20precision.%20The%20allowed%20range%20of%20p%20is%20from%200%20to%206.) will also keep the `time` data type allowing you to use adequate functions and operators:

   > `time`, `timestamp`, and `interval` accept an optional precision value p which specifies the number of fractional digits retained in the seconds field.

   Set to `0` it will round fractions of a second. It was initially suggested by someone else - best choice in my opinion - but the answer was removed when thread got falsely discarded as duplicate.
4. [date_trunc()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) lets you discard fractions, while keeping an appropriate type.

```sql
select now()::timestamp            as "now",
       to_char(now(),'HH:MI:SS')   as "to_char()",
       to_char(now(),'FMHH:MI:SS') as "fillmode", --trims one leading zero
       now()::time(0)              as "::time(0)",--rounds fractions
       date_trunc('seconds',now() )::time  as "date_trunc()";--discards fractions

/*          now             | to_char() | fillmode | ::time(0) | date_trunc()
----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------
 2022-11-14 09:03:04.810214 | 09:03:04  | 9:03:04  | 09:03:05  | 09:03:04
(1 row)
*/
```